# How to find rows which has a certain char less than a certain count?

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I am trying to write a `shell`/`perl` command which will give me the row numbers, which has number of fields less than a certain count.
E.g. I have a comma-delimited text file. I am trying to find those rows which has less than, say 15, fields. So I guess the problem essentially boils down to returning rows which has less than 14 commas.

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this easily in bash by calling awk. This sort of script is exactly what awk was designed to do.

```
awk -F, '{ if (NF < 15 ) print NR "," $0 }' fileToTest
```

`-F,` tells awk to split each line on the comma char, AND `NF` (Number_of_Fields) indicates how  many fields where split in each line. Change the 15 value as needed to help you validate your files.

Don't forget that CSV files may have commas embedded inside the fields if the field is surrounded by quotes, i.e.

```
 fld1, "text for, fld2", fld3, fld4,....
```

Solving that problem is significantly harder Use a tab char to separate your fields (or some other character you can be sure will never appear in your data), and then sleep easy at night ;-)

I hope this helps.

Comment: @shelter: Thanks a lot for the quick response. But I guess in the 'if' condition, the sign should be '<', and not '>', since I want rows which has fields less than 15.

Comment: also, how can i get the line numbers?

Comment: Added NR (Number_of_Record) (line number) to output, separated with comma char.

Comment: Found it: `awk -F, 'BEGIN {x=1}; { if (NF < 65 ) print x,$0;  x++}' my-comma-file.txt`

Comment: That works too. Allow me to say that Awk (and perl) have a lot of built in variables that they ***maintain automatically*** (each time you read a record and for other actions that occur). Good luck!

Comment: can write in more awk-ish style: `awk -F, 'NF<15 {print NR, $0}'`

Answer (score 4):

### Cute version

```
perl -lne 'print if tr/,// < 14
```

`tr/x//` is a Perl idiom for counting the number of `x`es in a string.

### More flexible version

```
perl -F, -lane 'print if @F < 15`
```

`-a` enables "autosplit mode", `-F` sets the delimiter to comma, and the code in the `-e` says to print if there are less than 15 fields. This is nice if you eventually want to do something else with the contents of the fields, since they're available in `@F` already split on comma.

### Properly CSV version

Doesn't make a nice one-liner, but you might consider using [Text::xSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text%3a%3axSV) or [Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Text%3a%3aCSV_XS) if your data is really CSV and not merely "comma separated" — the difference is that CSV can contain embedded commas, newlines, and other weird things by using quoted fields.

Answer (score 2):

You also asked for Perl. This is not the only way and it assumes the commas are always field delimiters–

```
perl -ne 'print "$.: $_" if 15 > split/,/' my-comma-file.txt
```

Comment: And to match the `awk` a little more closely: `perl -F, -ne 'print "$.: $_" if 15 > @F'`

Comment: The first stab was missing the `-a` switch, I think: `perl -aF, -ne 'print "$.: $_" if 15 > @F'` (@hobbs, you're too fast!)